# Javascript match and replace the following symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match and replace the following: `/?&` with `/?`

```
collage_url.match(/\/?&/) == '/?';
```

However this doesn't seem to work. Anyone able to help me out here, thanks

Comment: `?` has special meaning in regex, you need to escape it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need regex for this. Do this `collage_url = collage_url.replace('/?&', '/?')`

If you want to use regex, then do this `collage_url = collage_url.replace(/\/\?&/, '/?')` as `?` represents optional quantifier.

Comment: your answers also in first replace() first argument is string whereas in second not?

Comment: regex is not a string

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.replace`

```
'url/?&'.replace(/\/\?&/, '/?')
// => "url/?"
```

`?` has special meaning in regular expression: 0 or 1 match of preceding pattern; You need to escape `?` to match it literally.

Comment: Is `/\/\?&/` should n't be as string? I mean `'/\/\?&/'`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, Why? `/\/\?&/` is an regular expression literal. It's equivalent to `new RegExp('\\/\\?&')`

Comment: But below in Narendra's answer in first replace he is using string.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, `String.replace` accepts both string, regular expression object as the first parameter. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace